# How to size database columns for storing Salesforce fields; length or bytelength?

Tags: rest-api, sobject, sobjectfield, character-encoding

All fields in Salesforce have two lengths; a unicode character length and bytes length; our org uses UTF-8. We're sizing tables/columns in Oracle to accomodate our data from the cloud, my question is regarding Salesforce "string/text" types.

Why do all string fields show bytes length exactly 3 times larger than character length? For instance, a given field shows `length=80`, `bytelength=240`. UTF-8 is variable up to 4 bytes, so why is `bytelength` not 320 in this case?

When sizing columns for RDBMS, which length should be used? For instance, in Oracle 10, we use `NVARCHAR2` for strings, the column is sized in bytes, so the assumption is to use NVARCHAR2(bytelength).

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but keep in mind that matching salesforce lengths needs a little caution.  My understanding is that a salesforce text field can contain more characters than the 'limit' imposed by the supposed number of characters. i.e.  If a field was 255, and is then reduced to 40, it could contain data that was up to 255 in length.  see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203143/when-are-text-field-lengths-enforced-in-salesforce-can-i-get-the-actual-field-l

Comment: Not an immediate concern for us, but thanks for the tip (did not know that)